# How do I code this SQL query in Laravel? Correct way to code mySQL HAVING

Tags: mysql, laravel

The `SQL` statement below returns the right result, however I am having trouble converting this to `Laravel` and finding the right way to code `Count(*) >=2` .

```
SELECT  `column_id` 
FROM  `table` 
WHERE  `game_id` 
IN ( 13, 14 ) 
GROUP BY  `column_id` 
HAVING COUNT( * ) >=2
```

Comment: Vote to close because of lack of effort from OP

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence... It took me three hours to work out how to write the correct SQL query!!!, I could add to the post if you want with all the failed attempts to get this code working in laravel, if you believe it is of use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `havingRaw()`

```php
DB::table('table')
->select('column_id')
->whereIn('game_id', array(13, 14))
->groupBy('column_id')
->havingRaw('COUNT(*) >=?', array(2))
->get();
```

Comment: Thank you ->havingRaw() was what I was looking for :-)